# Can I compute lenght of mkv/avi movie and jump to the middle via cli in vlc?

Tags: vlc, dlna, mediatomb

It is possible in headless MEDIATOMB/VLC streaming server to compute somehow lenght of movie and jump via command line to the middle of this movie?
In mediatomb when I'm using transcode it is impossible to fast forward/backward movie. So Maybe i can create another "virtual object" for every long movie to start from a middle.